# Show rounded <a> link with <span> to act as a rounded button

Tags: javascript, css

I am customizing the SharePoint online main menu, and to do so i added this javaScript to add a button at the end of the menu items:-

```
var e = document.createElement('div');
e.classList.add('ms-HorizontalNavItem');

e.innerHTML = "<a data-automation-id='button-web-part' href='https://***/' target='_blank' class='ms-Button ms-Button--primary root-251' data-is-focusable='true' style='background-Color:green;color:while'><span class='ms-Button-flexContainer flexContainer-252' data-automationid='splitbuttonprimary'><span class='ms-Button-textContainer textContainer-253'><span style='color:while'>Shop me some</span></span></span></a>";



var ele = document.querySelectorAll('[role="menubar"]');
ele[0].appendChild(e);
```

now i result i got will be as follow:-

[image]

but i want the item/button to be as follow, bigger with rounded corners:-

[image]

any advice?

Comment: Can you try applying a bit of padding and `border-radius` on the `a` element?

Comment: css code added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- just add `padding` and text `color` on `<a>`

```html
<a data-automation-id='button-web-part' href='https://fullstackgear.com.au/' target='_blank' class='ms-Button ms-Button--primary root-251' data-is-focusable='true' style='background-Color:green; text-decoration: none; padding: 10px 20px; border-radius: 10px;
    background-Color: green; '><span class='ms-Button-flexContainer flexContainer-252' data-automationid='splitbuttonprimary'><span class='ms-Button-textContainer textContainer-253'><span style='color: #fff;'>Shop me some</span></span></span></a>
```

Comment: your code worked for me , thanks.. but may i ask you to remove the URL inside <a> as it contain real customer url,, i added by mistake inside my original question..